# checking a condition only in the first cycle and in the rest cycles execute some code

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

Is there is way to check a condition only in the first cycle of the for loop and in the rest cycles execute some code , if condition was evaluated to true? I have a for loop and two basic conditions within it, which need to be checked only in the first cycle. If either of them is true, then one or another piece of code is being executed for all other cycles. I can't check for these conditions in other cycles but the first one,because both would be true, and it's not what I need((

```
    public void someMethod() {
    int index;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (j == 0 && cond1 == true && cond2 == true) {
            methodXForTheFirstCycle();// this method will change cond2
            methodXForTheRestCycles();// not the right place to put it
        } else if (j == 0 && cond1 == true) {// and cond2 == false
            methodYForTheFirstCycle();// this method will change cond2
            methodYForTheRestCycles();// not the right place to put it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have got an `else` block for every `if-else if` block. Make use of that.

Comment: If it's only the first run, and it will always be the first run, check the conditional **outside** of a for-loop, setting the value of that conditional to a variable, and then use that variable to control what code gets executed later. Also, you're question is a little contrived - it would be easier to show actual code and explain what you're actually doing so we can see your logic and ofter real advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused, because your code does nothing if `j!=0` - so why the loop at all?

I would split the loop up. Pull out `i==0` which calls the first method, and then a loop for `i=1 .. 9`

This is what I think you mean by your description:

```
public void someMethod() {
  int index;
  if (cond1) {
    if (cond2) {
      methodXForTheFirstCycle();
      for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        methodXForTheRestCycles();
      }
    } else {
      methodYForTheFirstCycle();
      for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        methodYForTheRestCycles();   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: cond1 == true is a redundant truth, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_theory_of_truth (aka verbiage ;)

Comment: Was going to post an answer and then realized it was too close to yours to bother.  So I submitted a small edit which moved the method calls a bit to be what I think you were going for. If I was wrong, feel free to reject it =)

Comment: thanks! it seems to be what I've been looking for!) If it won't work out, I'll post the actual code(already typed it, but it's late in here, so I'll try to make use of your advice right tomorrow morning!) @MrSmith42

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you un roll your loop a little.

```
if (cond1)
   // j == 0
   if (cond2) 
        methodXForTheFirstCycle();
   else 
        methodYForTheFirstCycle();
   cond2 = !cond2;

   for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
     if (cond2)
        methodXForTheRestCycle();
     else 
        methodYForTheRestCycle();
     cond2 = !cond2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, what you can do is to check for the two conditions once and break if they fail. If they succeed set a flag to true, such that it bypasses the checks in subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new flag(boolean) and also there is no need to compare boolean as true as below:

```
public void someMethod() {
  int index;
  boolean firstConditionSuccess = false;
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (j == 0 && cond1 && cond2) {
        methodXForTheFirstCycle();
        firstConditionSuccess = true;
    } else if (j == 0 && cond1) {// and cond2 == false
        methodYForTheFirstCycle();
        firstConditionSuccess = true;
    }
    if(firstConditionSuccess ){
       methodYForTheRestCycles();
    }
 }
}
```